# Does my Scrabble play have to be all adjacent tiles?

Tags: scrabble, scoring

Do all tiles played in one move need to be adjacent to each other? Example - there is a Y on the board, can a player place the letter E on both sides to make the word EYE ?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate) question: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/54110/was-it-ever-the-case-that-tiles-had-to-be-placed-contiguously

Answer (score 8):

No, they need only be in a single line.

For example, your `EYE` is allowed.

The [official Scrabble rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules) has this legitimate example for playing FARM across a previous play of HORN:

[image: Turn 1: "HORN". Turn 2: Playing F,A, and M to make "FARM" across the R in "HORN"]

Comment: They also need to form a single word. You can't play I and O under the p and y of play in a single turn for example.