# Is this a legal move in scrabble?

Tags: scrabble

In a game of Scrabble, the original word on the board was “AMEND”:

```
AMEND
```

I added an ‘S’ to the end to spell the word “SPA” vertically.

```
AMENDS
     P
     A
```

I thought it was a legal move, but it was contested by one of my opponents. Is this a legal move or not?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that is a legal play.

As long as your tiles are all in a single row/column and form a single word it's a legal play.  This [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/52902/does-my-scrabble-play-have-to-be-all-adjacent-tiles) explains this further.

Your play is a very common technique to get extra points.  The linked to answers in the comments are examples of similar plays that get many extra points.  As @jolenealaska says, it was a very good play.